# Accessing Neo4j Node property using cypher in python

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to get the node property in python, which  I earlier created with name property as Marco

```
student = db.labels.create("Student")
u1 = db.nodes.create(name="Marco")
student.add(u1)
```

When I queried on neo4j UI using query

```
MATCH (n:Student) where n.name="gaurav" RETURN n.name
```

It returned me property of the node.

But how do I get same property in python, presently I'm using below script to query the DB, but I dont know how to get property name from this query sequence.

```
result = db.query("MATCH (a:Student) WHERE a.name = {} RETURN a ", {"name": 
"Marco"}, returns=(client.Node))
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in  https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/04/06/getting-started-with-neo4j-and-python/ you can do this :

```
results = db.query("MATCH (a:Student) WHERE a.name = {} RETURN a ", {"name": 
"Marco"}, returns=(client.Node))

for r in results:
    print("(%s)" % (r[0]["name"]))
```

Hope this helps,
Tom